# How to have PHPUnit/Xdebug ignore 'Could not connect to debugging client'

Tags: phpunit, xdebug

I have my local PHP configured to run Xdebug.

But I don't always have my IDE turned on to listen for Xdebug. When that's the case, I can load web pages from my browser and run CLI PHP scripts without any problems - except for PHPUnit, which fails the test with this:

> Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(

How do I make PHPUnit or Xdebug ignore this error?

I don't want to have to keep restarting PHP to turn Xdebug on and off, and I don't want to have to fiddle with my browser or with environment variables to tell Xdebug whether to run or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting this error because you ask Xdebug to talk to your IDE. If it can't do that, you get this warning. That is a *feature*.

Two options:

1. You can prefix your `phpunit` with `XDEBUG_MODE=off` or `XDEBUG_MODE=coverage` if you need code coverage enabled: `XDEBUG_MODE=coverage phpunit …extra_params…`
2. Configure Xdebug's log file in your PHP ini file(s): `xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log`, in which case the warning goes into the log file.

Comment: Understood, it's a feature that's desirable most of the time. Method 1 works great, thanks!